# Arcpy reclassify all values to same number

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, raster, nodata

Using ArcGIS 10.1 and arcpy, is there a way to reclassify all values of a raster file to the same value (leaving NoData Values as "NoData")? Lets assume that I have no way of knowing what the actual (i.e original) values are, so defining a RemapRange from a very small to a very large number would be rather inelegant.

Basically, i'm missing a third option in the `arcpy.Reclassify()` tool. "missing values" can left alone (= "DATA") or turned into NoData (= "NODATA"), but not reclassified to a certain value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to convert all values to the same constant value and NoData should remain NoData.
Instead of Reclassify, use the [Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Con/009z00000005000000/) tool with your input raster as 'Input conditional raster', and the constant value as 'Input true raster or constant value'.

E.g.:

```
import arcpy
cst = 5                    # your constant value
outCon = Con(r"C:\data\intput.tif", cst)
outCon.save(r"C:\data\output.tif")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer! Didn't now this tool, it serves exactly my purpouse. I'd vote up, but lack the reputation.

Comment: Glad I could help. This tool is a classic one, try from time to time to take a few minutes to open the Toolbox and have a look at some tools' description, you might find other useful stuff.